# Swift: viewDidLoad() properly runs method inside, but wont run the code after the method?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a method being called inside viewDidLoad, and it works properly doing what it should. For some reason I am having trouble reaching any code after the w.getWeatherData() method is called. It does not attempt to run the next print statement.

Am I missing something? No errors or warnings.

If I comment out the getWeatherData method, then it runs the print statement afterwards. Very confused, please help if you can. Thank you!

```
class ForecastViewController: UIViewController{

let w = WeatherViewController()
let w2 = WeatherDataModel()

var city = ""



@IBOutlet weak var Day1: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let params : [String : String] = ["q" : city, "appid" : w.APP_ID]
    w.getWeatherData(url: w.FORECAST_URL, parameters: params)

    print("Attempting updateDayOfTheWeek Func")
    //updateDayOfTheWeek()

}

func updateDayOfTheWeek(){
    print("Updating UI Label")

}
}
```

Comment: The obvious explanation would be that your method is executed synchronously so the thread (the main thread in this case) is blocked until the method finishes. Can you share some specifics on how `getWeatherData` works?

Comment: Interesting. That definitely makes sense, that must be the reason then. I'll check through the method and see if there is anything holding it up, even though it appears to finish. Thank you!

Comment: The issue was that the method being run inside vieDidLoad was asynchronous. Just had to move that portion around rather than putting it inside viewDidLoad.